# How to keep figure captions in R Markdown when fig.retina is not 1

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I'm having trouble with figure captions in html documents generated using R Markdown. If I don't specify the fig.retina option, or if I set it to 1, the output document has a figure caption. If I set it to a value that isn't 1, however, the future caption is missing but the text for it is present as the alt text for the figure. How can I keep the figure captions?

An example:

````
---
title: "Example"
output:
  html_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    fig_retina: 2
---


Text text text

```{r fig.cap="Figure 1. Some random numbers"}
plot(rnorm(25),runif(25)) 
```
````

Renders to give a document with no figure caption, but if I change the value for fig.retina to 1 I get a figure caption. The same thing happens if I set fig.retina in the chunk rather than globally.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the relevant documentation

```
#' @param fig_retina Scaling to perform for retina displays (defaults to 2 when
#'   \code{fig_caption} is \code{FALSE}, which currently works for all widely
#'   used retina displays). Set to \code{NULL} to prevent retina scaling. Note
#'   that this will always be \code{NULL} when \code{keep_md} is specified (this
#'   is because \code{fig_retina} relies on outputting HTML directly into the
#'   markdown document).
#' @param fig_caption \code{TRUE} to render figures with captions
```

So if you don't specify the default will be 2.  I did find that if I changed your code to

````
---
title: "Example"
output:
  html_document:
    fig_caption: yes

---


Text text text

```{r fig.cap="Figure 1. Some random numbers"}
plot(rnorm(25),runif(25)) 
```
````

It showed the caption.

**update**

After looking around a bit I found this

> Note the chunk option fig.retina=1: without it, rmarkdown::render()
>   will generate plots for Retina displays, which means the plots are
>   written in raw `<img>` tags instead of `![]()`, and Pandoc will not be
>   able to generate figure captions in that case.

So probably you need to just use normal markdown for adding html for the caption.

Comment: Thanks Elin but I'm afraid I'd already worked that out - the question is really whether it's possible to get figure captions *and* have nice high resolution figures. If you set fig_caption: yes then you get low res figures, if you set fig_retina: 2 then you lose the figure captions.

Comment: No that code does have fig_retina: 2 ... that is the default and it gives you the caption.  The problem is that if you actually set fig_retina to 2 rather than letting the default handling do it you lose the captions .. like it is turning fig_caption to false.

Comment: That's not what I get - with your code I get a low-res figure but if I set fig_caption: no I get a high res figure. As it says in the docs you quoted, fig_retina defaults to 2 when fig_caption is false - it seems that when fig_caption is true is is set to 1. I get this result if I use RStudio to render the Rmd file or if I do it in the console with render(). It's weird.

Comment: I think that it's weird that there is no default if fig_caption is TRUE.

Comment: I think this has to do with pandoc, a couple of links are http://pandoc.org/README.html#images and http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.knitr/1031  Note the chunk option fig.retina=1: without it, rmarkdown::render()
> will generate plots for Retina displays, which means the plots are
> written in raw <img> tags instead of ![](), and Pandoc will not be
> able to generate figure captions in that case.

Comment: Thanks Elin, you've been really helpful.