# How Do I Get Back to a Simple Markdown Format for Image Captions Using RStudio (knitr?)?

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I just updated several R packages and it seems to have introduced breaking changes in the production of markdown interim output from `Rmd` documents in RStudio.

Assuming `knitr` is still used by RStudio to generate `md` from `Rmd` on the way to producing `html`, expressions of the form:

````
---
output:
  html_document:
    keep_md: yes
---
```{r myimg, fig.cap="My caption"}
library(ggplot2)
qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data = iris, color = Species)
```
````

that used to render something of the form:

```
![My caption](myimg.png)
```

now get rendered *in the markdown* as:

```
<div class="figure">
<img src="myimg.png" alt="My caption"  />
<p class="caption">My caption</p>
</div>
```

which is not what I want at all.

How do I the original, simpler `md` formatting back?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30286067/2706569) looks related. But something is quite strange with this: A chunk with `fig.retina = 1` produces a markdown image when using `knit()` but the output is a HTML image when using the "Knit HTML" button.

Comment: @CL I fiddled with the retina setting but couldn't get it to give me the md. I think that maybe the markdown plotting has been undergoing some maintenance? I flagged an issue on the Github repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This issue](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1160) has been [fixed](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/5e227425e7da7966bc5bbd81cf0dbbd72a65f009) in **knitr** (>= 1.12.6) currently on [Github](https://github.com/yihui/knitr#installation). I was writing out the HTML code for images to support another package that I was working on, and I should have enabled this only conditionally. Now you should be able to see the original `![]()` syntax in the Markdown output.

Comment: Thanks; there is still an empty <!-- --> appearing though, which clutters the md?